# How to get the sale data for previous three years in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

Get the yearly and monthly data for previous 3 years or 2 years where sum of sale of previous years should be in column headers.
I'm a beginner to the sql and bigquery.
Something as shown below.

| Months | Sale 2023 | Sale 2022 | Sale 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 50 | 40 | 50 |
| Feb | 40 | 20 | 40 |
| Mar | 20 | 50 | 20 |
| Apr | 50 | 40 | 50 |
| May | 40 | 20 | 40 |
| Jun | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| Jul | 50 | 50 | 20 |
| Aug | 40 | 40 | 50 |
| Sep | 20 | 20 | 40 |
| Oct | 50 | 50 | 20 |
| Nov | 40 | 40 | 50 |
| Dec | 20 | 40 | 40 |

I wrote the query

```sql
WITH previous AS (
  SELECT
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sell_date) - 1 AS previous_year,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sell_date) AS month,
  SUM(sum_sale_value) AS monthly_sellout
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sell_date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE())
  GROUP BY
  previous_year,
  month
)
SELECT 
  month,
  COALESCE(SUM(monthly_sellout), 0) AS previous_year_monthly_sellout
FROM
  previous
GROUP BY 
  month
ORDER BY 
  month;
```

Comment: Can I request for what your reference table looks like ?